# Recover data: HDD not detected in bios and disk utility

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have hard disk which is not detected in bios and also in disk utility.
I've tried to mount in another system, still same issue and also tried to mount in Windows still same issue. I've used `ddrescue` in past but it was in case where hard drive was detected.

How can I recover data in this case?

Comment: The tools available to normal users (you and me) for recovery need the drive to be recognized as a mass storage device `/dev/sdx`. What kind of drive is it, an internal SATA drive or an external drive (in a casing and connected via USB)? Has the drive worked for you earlier, but stopped working)? Maybe the following link can help you analyze the problem, [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: "I have hard disk which is not detected in bios"  "How can I recover data in this case?" That reads as a broken hard disk so probably never. If the controller is fried, the connection got an electrical surge it is busted beyond repair. For these kind of problems you depend on a backup.

Comment: @sudodus it is internal SATA and seems like hard drive is dead.

Comment: @Rinzwind I agree... Is there any third party tool to recover data of dead hdd in Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm afraid that there is nothing to peel off in this case, and that your SATA HDD is damaged beyond repair for a normal user. If the data on it are extremely valuable, you can get help from a specialized company, but it would be very expensive.

Comment: @daisy nope. Well... technically there might be but you need a professional service I found one online (dutch though) and they ask  € 742,98  for 1 hard disk :P

Comment: @sudodus not just very expensive :P very very very very expensive

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a broken SATA drive (a hardware problem and *technically off-topic here*, but I'll let it slide as it's an issue occurring a lot) and now it depends where the problem is:

#### Disk platters:

[image: Disk platters]

- Professional dust-free room repair only, **sorry!**

## OR

#### Disk controller:

[image: Controller Board]

- Buy an identical second-hand working one on e-Bay
- Remove its controller board
- Remove your HDD
- Remove its controller board
- Add the "new" controller board
- Reinsert repaired HDD

### How do you know which of the 2 problems you have?

#### Disk platters:

- Ticking noises before it gave up completely
- Higher pitched tone before it gave up
- Doesn't spin up, but gets extremely hot

[Source for controller pic](http://notebooks.com/2010/09/07/how-to-install-an-old-notebook-hard-drive-in-an-external-drive-enclosure/)
[Source for Disk platter pic](https://www.anandtech.com/show/11084/seagate-confirms-plans-for-12-tb-hdd-in-near-future-16-tb-hdd-due-in-2018)

Comment: Indeed this is useful as I was suggested the same before. I've asked the question considering the solution if there's any third party software available in Ubuntu but now it seems like only a hardware solution. Thanks though.

Comment: I know: It's just that I've been there before too and been able to repair an old HDD that way and recover crucial data by borrowing someone else's controller for 24h...  **;-)**   Thanks for the upvote! @daisy